# No sbaz in scala directory after installing scala-2.9.2.msi (on Windows)

Tags: windows, scala, installation, sbaz

Should I somehow download it separately or this is a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was mentioned in the comments at the bottom of the 2.9.2.final [release notes](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/12603).  Apparently it was commented as "sbaz is deprecated and gone".  So, it appears it's not a bug, it's just not there in that release.

See more discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/scala-language/QK4rTszzIeM/Mu4N_1zu_K8J) (including the source of the above comment).

Comment: Was it replaced with something better?

Comment: Reading through the discussion, nothing is mentioned as a replacement.

Comment: LOST: re: replacement, it depends on what you were doing with sbaz. I found that using [sbt](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt) for my builds meant that I never had to install jars via sbaz.

Comment: Well, it _was_ a bug in the release process. Since it's a point release, sbaz should have been bundled. Since it's an entirely new (and mostly automated) release process, and sbaz was deprecated, it was forgotten. And it's not worth the effort correcting the problem, so it's a "won't fix".